# Update codebasehq.com on deploy with Capistrano 3

Tags: deployment, capistrano3

The codebase4 gem is outdated (Capistrano 2 only) and I was wondering how to get it working with Capistrano 3 as it does away with recipes and uses tasks instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task does the job quite nicely in combination with the gem:

```
namespace :codebase do
  desc "Logs the deployment of your Codebase 4 repository"
  task :log_deployment do

    previous_revision = fetch :previous_revision
    current_revision = fetch :current_revision

    if previous_revision == current_revision
      puts "\e[31m    The old revision & new revision are the same - you didn't deploy anything new. Skipping logging.\e[0m"
      next
    end

    cmd = ["cb deploy #{previous_revision or "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"} #{current_revision}"]

    if respond_to?(:environment)
      set :environment, environment
    elsif respond_to?(:rails_env)
      set :environment, rails_env
    end

    branch = fetch :branch
    roles = fetch :roles
    stage = fetch :stage
    app = fetch :application

    cmd << "-s #{app}"
    cmd << "-b #{branch}"
    cmd << "-e #{stage}"

    ## get the repo and project name etc...
    account, project, repo = nil, nil, nil
    case fetch(:repo_url)
    when /git\@codebasehq.com\:(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)\.git\z/
      account, project, repo = $1, $2, $3
    when /ssh:\/\/.+\@codebasehq.com\/(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)\.hg\z/
      account, project, repo = $1, $2, $3
    when /https?:\/\/.+\@(.+)\.codebasehq.com\/(.+)\/(.+)\.(?:hg|svn)\z/
      account, project, repo = $1, $2, $3
    when /https?:\/\/(?:.+\@)?(.+)\.svn\.codebasehq.com\/(.+?)\/(.+?)(?:\/.*)\z/
      account, project, repo = $1, $2, $3
    else
      puts "! Repository path not supported by deployment logging"
      next
    end

    cmd << "-r #{project}:#{repo}"
    cmd << "-h #{account}.codebasehq.com"
    cmd << "--protocol https"

    run_locally do
      execute cmd.join(' ') + "; true"
    end

  end
end
```

Example deploy:

```
namespace :deploy do
    after 'deploy:symlink:release', 'codebase:log_deployment'
end
```

If you are running a version of Capistrano that has previous revision removed.

Add this to you deploy file or add as another custom task file:

```
on roles(:app) do
  within current_path do
    revision = capture "cat #{current_path}/REVISION"
    set :previous_revision, revision
  end
end
```

Then the revision will be picked up as normal.

```
previous_revision = fetch :previous_revision
current_revision = fetch :current_revision
```

My Ruby is a bit rusty at the moment so if this can be consolidated/improved please let me know, thanks.

Comment: Does this really work? For me, the `fetch :previous_revision` and the `fetch :current_revision` return blank strings.

Comment: Yes we are using this on all of our sites and have no issues. It might be the version of capistrano you are using? Currently we are locked at 3.2.1.

Comment: That may be the issue. The previous_revision tagging feature has been removed in the newer versions of Capistrano. [Check here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/commit/b1cbb0cd54ed79960ccee0feab52ead209512858)

Comment: Thanks for the update. If you figure it out post it here please if not I'll try and look at this later today and do the same.

Comment: Please see the edit above, I just tested it and it logged deployment fine on 3.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

The `codebase4` gem has been updated to include a Capistrano 3 version of the script.

The following works for me (tested on a Rails 4 project).

In the Capfile, add the following:

```
require 'capistrano/git'
require 'codebase/capistrano3'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/**/*.rb').each { |r| import r }
```

Add the following task somewhere in your deploy scripts. I put it in a separate file called `lib/capistrano/tasks/git.cap`.

```
namespace :git do
  desc 'Determine the previous revision that was deployed'
  task :set_previous_revision do
    on release_roles :all do
      within repo_path do
        with fetch(:git_environmental_variables) do
          set :previous_revision, strategy.fetch_revision
        end
      end
    end
  end

  before 'git:update', 'git:set_previous_revision'
end
```

That's it.

I have been trying to make this work on a Rails 3 project for a long time, but for some reason, by the time the `current_revision` and `previous_revision` variables are `fetch`ed (at the end of the deploy process, when the deploy tracking code is executed), the variables don't exist; they return blank strings.

The same code works flawlessly on a Rails 4 project. I am not sure if there is something happening which clears those 2 variables before the deploy tracking code runs.